# <hr> not showing

Tags: html, css

I have a `<hr>` which isn't showing.

HTML:

```
<div id="line"><hr /></div>
```

CSS:

```
hr {
    border: 0;
    width: 96%;
    color: #FFFF00;
    height: 1px;
}


#line {
    float: left;
    width: 731px;
    height: 10px;
}
```

Any ideas why it's not showing?

Comment: Look at this http://jsfiddle.net/quEUF/1/

Comment: He already use <hr/> to display line then why need to take border?

Comment: Yes because you have used color, see my answer below

Answer (score 92, accepted):

try this code :

```
hr {
  border: 0;
  clear:both;
  display:block;
  width: 96%;               
  background-color:#FFFF00;
  height: 1px;
}
```

JSFiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/EXXrB/

Hope it will help you to resolve your problem.

Comment: Is this just a bug with Bootstrap 4? Thanks

Comment: It is old question , so I don't think there was any relation with Bootstrap 4. Let me know if you still have any confusion.

Comment: This issue comes up in Bootstrap 4. Your code fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

Remove `border: 0;` from the css rule for `hr`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yknEZ/)

Comment: the color he has used into his code is Yellow, there is no yellow colored line into your demo.

Comment: I have checked it into chrome

Answer (score 4):

Simple Way to get best Horizontal Line

```
. horizontalLine {  
    border: none; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid gainsboro;  
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
hr
{
border:solid 1px black;
width: 96%;
color: #FFFF00;
height: 1px;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to use `border:0px;`, then set `height:1px;` and set `background:#FFFF00;`

(OR)
`border:1px solid #FFFF00;` and `height:0px;`

That might do the trick!

Either stick with border color to show a horizontal line or go with the background color for **`<HR> tag`**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
hr {
border: 0;
clear:both;
display:block;
width: 96%;
color: #FFFF00;
height: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
hr {
  width: 80%
  border-color: black
}
```

Or if it's Tailwind CSS

```
.hr {
  @apply w-4/5 border-black
}
```